# How can I replace my array key to value in other key?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, replace, key

```
array(22) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(33) "White shirt - blue logo"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "10.00"
    ["img"]=>
    string(5) "2.jpg"
    ["text"]=>
    string(865) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    ["url"]=>
    string(26) "voltarity-white-red-shirt2"
  }
another array...
another array...
}
```

So I would like to change my array key [0] to my value in ["url"], is it possible?
BTW that array is created from mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new associative array using the 'url' as the key.

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($oldArray as $row) {
    $newArray[$row['url']] = $row;
}
```

Obviously, if you have 2 rows with the same value for 'url' the second row will overwrite the first row. If you need to allow multiple rows to have the same value for 'url' then you can use this loop instead.

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($oldArray as $row) {
    if (isset($newArray[$row['url']]) {
        if (is_array($newArray[$row['url']])) {
            $newArray[$row['url']][] = $row;
        } else {
            $newArray[$row['url']] = array($newArray[$row['url']], $row);
        }
    } else {
        $newArray[$row['url']] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could extend this so that overwrites won't happen: `$newArray[$row['url']][] = $row` -- but you must also be prepared to deal with this multidim array.